# Error initializing noflo nodejs

Tags: noflo

I am getting the following error while trying to setup my node.js server. I am using the latest version of noflo and node.js. Is anyone else seeing this behaviour for NoFlo on Windows?

Here is the command and error:

*C:\Users\Johan\Source\Repos\HelloNoFlow>node node_modules.bin\noflo-nodejs-init --help

```
C:\Users\Johan\Source\Repos\HelloNoFlow\node_modules\.bin\noflo-nodejs-init:2 basedir=`dirname "$0"`*  
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're following this [guide](http://flowhub.io/documentation/getting-started-node/) - which has wrong instructions on the execution.

This works for me on Windows:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\noflo-nodejs-init --help"
```

This is because the target is a *shell script* instead of Javascript. Executing `node <shell script>` is not going to work.

Note: The same should apply to starting "noflo-nodejs".

---

#### UPDATES (19/2/17)

1. The guide link has changed to https://docs.flowhub.io/getting-started-node
2. I no longer work on the project that uses noflo, but I find that the [script](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-nodejs/blob/master/bin/noflo-nodejs-init) has been converted to CoffeeScript. So this workaround might not be needed anymore

Comment: Can you please update the answer i have this error with 'noflo-nodejs-init' this module not being found in the latest code how do i fix this is ther any other ways to install that locally ?